# How to properly compare two Unix timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, unix, timestamp, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to show a popup message if the unix timestamp of the current date is equals to the defined unix timestamp of the popup.

So in order to do that, I added this at the Controller:

```
if($popup->datep == now()->timestamp){
    $output .=' <a href=" '.$popup->linkp.' "><img src=" '. URL::to('popups/'.$popup->image_path).' " style="width: 100%;"></a>';
}
```

And now the `$popup->datep` shows `1636403400` and `now()->timestamp` shows `1636355812`.

But the comparison of them always returns **TRUE** and shows the popup message. Even I enter a timestamp of next year!

So what's going wrong here? How can I properly compare two Unix timestamps together and show some results based on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date1= $popup->datep;
$date2 = Carbon::now;

$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);
$date2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date2);

$result = $date1->eq($date2);

if($result === true){
  dd("equal");
}
```

you need to take date and format same and then you can you conditional.

Comment: The separation symbol could not be found The separation symbol could not be found Data missing

Comment: I think your version not support eq. try this. $result = $date1 === $date2;

Comment: This error is referring to the line before that. I just asked a new question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880668/the-separation-symbol-could-not-be-found-data-missing

Comment: Also it is not working if statement cause of that i made it up if equal then make if.