# The separation symbol could not be found Data missing

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-5.8, php-carbon

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to show a popup message if the UNIX timestamp of the current date is equal to the defined Unix timestamp of the popup.

So in order to do that, I added this at the Controller:

```
$date1= $popup->datep; // returns 1636403400

$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1);

dd($date1);
```

But instead of getting the result of `$date1`, I get this error:

> The separation symbol could not be found Data missing

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: @brombeer Now I get `syntax error, unexpected '$date1` and referring to: `$date1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date1); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a format that is clearly not an unix timestamp. Use method for the timestamp.

```
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($popup->datep);
```

If you want to compare it to be the same date, you should do the following. I don't assume you want to compare it by the hour or second, that those will almost never match.

```
$date->startOfDay()->eq(now()->startOfDay());
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Carbon Docs:

> createFromFormat() is mostly a wrapper for the base php function DateTime::createFromFormat.

which is means that your second parameter must be a valid date/time format, not a timestamp.

The [`DateTime::create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) docs:

> $datetime
> String representing the time.

Instead, you need to use the `createFromTimestamp` instantiator.

```
$date1 = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($date1);
```